# Ubuntu doesn`t launch, cant get to grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, startup

To start of Im not very versed with ubuntu or linux in general.
So today my laptop wouldnt start ubuntu. After staring, it only showed a black screen or the lenovo startup logo. I also was unable to get to the grub menu, holding shift didnt work. I`m currently using the try out version from the installation stick.
I ran boot-repair but it doesnt give me any option for repair.

I tried to use fdisk but not sure what to really do with it. This is the output from fdisk -l: (Cruzer Blade is the USB stick)

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 2.06 GiB, 2213470208 bytes, 4323184 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.45 MiB, 58142720 bytes, 113560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 51.04 MiB, 53522432 bytes, 104536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 64.77 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 218.99 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 32.27 MiB, 33841152 bytes, 66096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.32 GiB, 15376318464 bytes, 30031872 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AF8737A9-1E23-4373-B87A-C8B16199D461

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       64  5494643  5494580  2.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  5494644  5504683    10040  4.9M EFI System
/dev/sda3  5504684  5505283      600  300K Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  5509120 30031808 24522689 11.7G Linux filesystem
```

I don`t know what to do to get Ubuntu to start working. I would really appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Hirsute is version 21.04 of Ubuntu that went End Of Life back in January 2022 and is no longer supported. It is recommended to install a supported version. Supported versions right now are 18.04 LTS (Soon to go EOL next year), 20.04 LTS and 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Thanks, it worked (I used 22.04 LTS). However it doesnt give me the option to do anything other than create a summary.